# Migrating from OpenSSL1 to OpenSSL3 on Alpine

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, alpine-linux

Started to migrate from OpenSSL1 to OpenSSL3+fips in Alpine3.18
The following command is used to signed certificates, it works on OpenSSL1 however in OpenSSL3 the Certificate Version field is set to 1 (0x0) instead of 3 (0x2):

```
openssl x509 -req \
    -days 365 \
    -in certs/csr.pem \
    -CA certs/cert.pem \
    -CAkey certs/key.pem \
    -set_serial 1 \
    -outform PEM \
    -out signed_cert.pem \
    -sha256 \
    -extfile <(cat <(printf "[ v3_req ]")) \
    -extensions v3_req
```

After inspecting the certificates generated from OpenSSL1 and OpenSSL3 with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in signed_cert.pem`, all fields seem to be the same except for the version. I haven't been able to find a similar issue online. Hoping for suggestions.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/979094/openssl-keeps-creating-v1-certificate-instead-of-v3 ?

Comment: Not the same considering OpenSSL3 wasn't out then and it works on OpenSSL1

Comment: You specify extfile/extensions that doesn't contain any extension(s), so the cert doesn't either, and an **X.509 cert with no extensions** (and no UIDs) can be v1 -- and [according to RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.1) **SHOULD be v1** (though 2119 "SHOULD" is not mandatory). Setting v3 in older OpenSSL (0.9 as well as 1.0 and 1.1) was arguably a bug, though not serious because most users who don't want extensions don't uselessly specify an empty list of extensions. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it as indeed this seems to be it.